# Unable to get related object in bookshelf.js

Tags: hapi.js, bookshelf.js

Does anyone know why I'm unable to access the **related** `author` for a given `book`?

`console.log(book.related('author').toJSON());` prints an **empty** object.

```js
var Book = Bookshelf.Model.extend({

  tableName: 'books',
  hasTimestamps: true,

  author: function() {
    return this.belongsTo(require('./author'));
  },

});

var Author = Bookshelf.Model.extend({

  tableName: 'authors',
  hasTimestamps: true,

  books: function(){
    return this.hasMany(require('./book'), 'author_id');
  },

});
```

In my `GET /books/{id}` route handler:

```js
var p = new Book({id: req.params.id}).fetch({
    withRelated: ['author']
  }).then(function(book){

      // THIS PRINTS AN EMPTY OBJECT
      console.log(book.related('author').toJSON());

      return {
        book: internals.renderbook(book)
      };
  });
```

If I try to print **without** `.toJSON()` it shows:

```js
{ attributes: {},
   _previousAttributes: {},
   changed: {},
   relations: {},
   cid: 'c12',
   relatedData: 
    { type: 'belongsTo',
      target: 
       { [Function]
         super_: [Object],
         NotFoundError: [Function: ErrorCtor],
         collection: [Function],
         forge: [Function],
         where: [Function],
         query: [Function],
         fetchAll: [Function],
         extend: [Function],
         __super__: [Object] },
      targetTableName: 'authors',
      targetIdAttribute: 'id',
      foreignKey: 'user_id',
      parentId: 'b3b35d4c-17c3-46bd-90c2-a17fe907b9b8',
      parentTableName: 'books',
      parentIdAttribute: 'id',
      parentFk: undefined } }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to test right now but the calls to require() in the definition of the models look weird to me ...  I would have written

```
author: function() {
  return this.belongsTo(Author);
}
```

and

```
books: function(){
  return this.hasMany(Book, 'author_id');
}
```

PS. Since I can't test right away, I wanted to make this a comment but I don't have reputation enough ...